# QSlider focus with a hotkey?

Tags: qt, hotkeys, qslider

The QSlider documentation says, "A slider accepts focus on Tab and provides both a mouse wheel and a keyboard interface."  Is there an easy way to assign a hotkey to it to give it focus similar to how one can assign an *Alt* key for QCheckboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an associated label, you should be able to use `QLabel::setBuddy(QWidget*)`. Otherwise, you could override the `keyPressEvent` for the parent form that would have focus and then call `QSlider::setFocus(Qt::FocusReason)`.

Comment: `setBuddy()` is the way to go.  After posting the question I started to override `keyPressEvent` and was getting 4 events for each keypress; I hadn't gotten a chance to figure that out when I came back here to see if there was any response - forget about the override!